# How to access internal typedefs by taking the type from a variable?

Tags: c++, c++11

If I have a variable of type `std::unordered_map<aaa, bbb>`, how can I access the `std::unordered_map<aaa, bbb>::iterator` typedef without having to always write the type itself but, for example, making the compiler infer it from an existing variable like `decltype(my_map)::iterator)`?

**EDIT:**

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

std::unordered_map<int, int> test()
{
    return std::unordered_map<int, int>();
}

int main()
{
    const auto &map = test();

    decltype(map)::const_iterator it;

    return 0;
}
```

Compile output:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:13:5: error: decltype evaluates to 'const std::unordered_map&', which is not a class or enumeration type
     decltype(map)::const_iterator it;
     ^
main.cpp:13:35: error: expected initializer before 'it'
     decltype(map)::const_iterator it;
                                   ^
```

Comment: By utilizing the `using` type aliases or perhaps the `auto` specifier.

Comment: Did you test `decltype`?  gcc seems perfectly happy with your suggestion.

Comment: `decltype` works on MSVC 14.1 too. I think that's the proper way to do it. Even though @Ron doesn't answer the question, he has a point. In most use cases you should not explicitly declare the type, eg `auto it = my_map.begin();`.

Comment: Your answer is in your question. Or you need to clarify why `decltype()` is not suitable.

Comment: @liliscent This is what I get:
https://imgur.com/a/GSNyM

Comment: @TesX See my answer.

Comment: If there is a code fault, _put the code and error clearly into the question as text_. You have been a SO member for almost eight years and should know to do this by now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you want to get the iterator type from a variable which might be a reference. You can use `std::remove_reference_t`:

```
#define get_iter_type(s) std::remove_reference_t<decltype(s)>::iterator
```

Then the following code will compile:

```
int main() {
    std::unordered_map<int, int> mp;
    const auto &s = mp;
    get_iter_type(s) it;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Multiple ways:

#### Type alias:

```
using my_map_it = std::unordered_map<aaa, bbb>::iterator;

my_map_it it;
```

#### `auto` deduce

```
std::unordered_map<aaa, bbb> my_map;

auto it = my_map.begin();
```

#### `decltype`

```
std::unordered_map<aaa, bbb> my_map;

decltype(my_map.begin()) it;

decltype(my_map)::iterator it; // also valid
```

Comment: The very last one doesn't work in the question (where `map` is a reference rather than an object).  The one immediately preceding it looks like what's asked for, though.

Comment: @TobySpeight yeah, sorry I've clarified that the type is a reference in the example code in the EDIT